# Process Class not reading file path

Tags: vb.net

My code is like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Process.Start("C:\Users\T\Desktop\IntSwitch\IntSwitch\IntSwitch\ipSwitchOnn.exe")
    End Sub
```

This works because the file path is correct, but is there a way just to use the file name?

This doesn't work:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Process.Start("ipSwitchOnn.exe")
    End Sub
```

but this will work:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Process.Start("IExplore.exe")
    End Sub
```

Where should the file be so that I can reference it without a complex file path?
It is saved as such:

(IntSwitch) > 
IntSwitch.sln (IntSwitch) >

[image]

Comment: It's basically the same whenever you use an incomplete path, i.e. a relative folder path or just a file name. The system will first look in the current directory for the current process (which will usually be the folder containing the current EXE but not always) and then it will examine the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: `Process.Start` checks in Environment Variables of the compute if there is any default location available for the specified `.exe` file. `IExplore.exe` is one such exe for which the default path available in Environment variable. If not found in environment variables it will search in the same directory where your program is running. In this case the program is running from `bin` directory so if `ipSwitchOnn.exe` is not available in `bin` directory it will not run.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I just tested with two files with the same name - one in the program folder and one in a folder specified in the `Path` environment variable, and the one in the program folder was opened preferentially when not specifying a path, so it appears that the program folder is examined before the `Path` variable.  That was certainly the case for a TXT file anyway.  Not sure if it is different for different types of files.

Comment: #Chetan Ranpariya Are you talking about the bin folder that is mentioned above in the image.  If so, I tried moving those files there, it didn't work.

Comment: Nope. The `Debug` or the `Release` folders inside the `Bin` folder. Which one, it depends on your current solution configuration. You could also copy the executable to the System (or the SysWOW64 folder) or Windows directories. If you're allowed to. Those are in the search path, too.

Comment: Or use `Environment.CurrentDirectory = "[SomeDir]"` to set the current working directory, or set a environment `PATH` entry with `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()`